# method 'assign' not supported in IE, what to do

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, babeljs

I have a small /javascript,Babel script, that runs just fine in Chrome and Firefox browsers, but it fails in Internet Explorer 11.

I hope somebody can help me.

Here is my function:

```
getDaysWithEvents() {
    // Get all the days in this months calendar view
    // Sibling Months included
    const days = this.getCalendarDays();

    // Set Range Limits on calendar
    this.calendar.setStartDate(days[0]);
    this.calendar.setEndDate(days[days.length - 1]);

    // Iterate over each of the supplied events
    this.props.events.forEach((eventItem) => {

        const eventStart = this.getCalendarDayObject(eventItem.start);
        const eventEnd = this.getCalendarDayObject(eventItem.end);
        const eventMeta = this.getEventMeta(days, eventStart, eventEnd);

        if (eventMeta.isVisibleInView) {
            const eventLength = eventMeta.visibleEventLength;
            const eventSlotIndex = days[eventMeta.firstVisibleDayIndex].eventSlots.indexOf(false);
            let dayIndex = 0;

            // For each day in the event
            while (dayIndex < eventLength) {
                // Clone the event object so we acn add day specfic data
                const eventData = Object.assign({}, eventItem);

                if (dayIndex === 0) {
                     // Flag first day of event
                    eventData.isFirstDay = true;
                }

                if (dayIndex === eventLength - 1) {
                    // Flag last day of event
                    eventData.isLastDay = true;
                }

                if (!eventData.isFirstDay || !eventData.isLastDay) {
                    // Flag between day of event
                    eventData.isBetweenDay = true;
                }

                // Apply Event Data to the correct slot for that day

                days[eventMeta.firstVisibleDayIndex + dayIndex].eventSlots[eventSlotIndex] = eventData;

                // Move to next day of event
                dayIndex++;
            }
        }
    });

    return days;
}
```

Error:

```
SCRIPT438: The object does not support the property or method 'assign'
```

This line has Error: `var eventData = Object.assign({}, eventItem);`

Can I rewrite this line..?

How to fix it ?

Comment: Use [the polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Polyfill)

Answer (score 15):

IE doesn't support Object.assign()

Use [polyfil](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```
    if (typeof Object.assign != 'function') {
  Object.assign = function(target, varArgs) { // .length of function is 2
    'use strict';
    if (target == null) { // TypeError if undefined or null
      throw new TypeError('Cannot convert undefined or null to object');
    }

    var to = Object(target);

    for (var index = 1; index < arguments.length; index++) {
      var nextSource = arguments[index];

      if (nextSource != null) { // Skip over if undefined or null
        for (var nextKey in nextSource) {
          // Avoid bugs when hasOwnProperty is shadowed
          if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(nextSource, nextKey)) {
            to[nextKey] = nextSource[nextKey];
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return to;
  };
}
```

If you are using babel

```
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-object-assign
```

using .babelrc

```
{
  "plugins": ["transform-object-assign"]
}
```

you can find other methods [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-assign/#usage-via-babelrc-recommended-)

Comment: Should give attribution to source of polyfill, not just copy it

Comment: Iam new to Javascript. How to use Use polyfil ?

Just copy the Abov code in my javascript function ?

Comment: Dinesh...are you simply going to ignore attribution? That is called *"plagiarism"*

Comment: @Kim Hansen load this piece of code before loading your js code

Comment: @charlietfl thanks for your info. i update with attribution. actually i forgot to add attributions

Comment: I have put your code abov my Function. But its not working.
I forgot to mension that iam using Barbel, jxs.

I have updated my script abov. Now i include hole script

Comment: i updated my answer please check. may i know how you are using babel?

Answer (score 8):

If you are using **jquery**, you can try [jQuery.extend( target [, object1 ] [, objectN ] )](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/). Your code:

```
const eventData = $.extend({}, eventItem);
```

Comment: Simple is always best assuming you can use jquery. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Dinesh undefined's answer is outdated as far as the `babel` part goes. This is how it's done today.

On the commandline:

`npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-transform-object-assign`

In your `.babelrc`:

`{
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-transform-object-assign"]
}`

[Source](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-plugin-transform-object-assign.html)