# add property to object with spread operator

Tags: javascript

I use a spread operator in my code to add a property to an object but this is not supported by IE 9. The important part is `...currentItem`

```js
const data = [
  [{
    name: "item 3",
    value: 2
  }],
  [{
    name: "item 4",
    value: 4535
  }, {
    name: "item 5",
    value: 897
  }]
];

$(document).ready(() => {

  const newData = data.map(subArr =>
    subArr.map((currentItem, index) => ({ ...currentItem,
      position: index - (subArr.length - 1) * 0.5
    }))
  );

  console.log(newData);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I tried to convert this to a code that is not using the spread operator

```js
const data = [
  [{
    name: "item 3",
    value: 2
  }],
  [{
    name: "item 4",
    value: 4535
  }, {
    name: "item 5",
    value: 897
  }]
];

$(document).ready(() => {

  const newData = data.map(subArr =>
    subArr.map((currentItem, index) => ({
      name: currentItem.name,
      value: currentItem.value,
      position: index - (subArr.length - 1) * 0.5
    }))
  );

  console.log(newData);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and this works really fine. But the problem is, that I have to write down all the properties of the current object. Let's assume there would be more than five properties. So I tried to add the new property to the current object by going for this code

```js
const data = [
  [{
    name: "item 3",
    value: 2
  }],
  [{
    name: "item 4",
    value: 4535
  }, {
    name: "item 5",
    value: 897
  }]
];

$(document).ready(() => {

  const newData = data.map(subArr =>
    subArr.map((currentItem, index) => (
      currentItem.position = index - (subArr.length - 1) * 0.5
      /* currentItem["position"] = index - (subArr.length - 1) * 0.5 */
    ))
  );

  console.log(newData);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

but now the object gets converted to the single property I want to add. So this is not working. How can I add the new property to the object within the `arr.map` loop?

**Important:** Using Jquery is just an example. Please provide solutions without using Jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Spread operators can be replaced with `Object.assign`, however that isn't supported in ie.

You can polyfill it as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44244468/method-assign-not-supported-in-ie-what-to-do):

```js
 if (typeof Object.assign != 'function') {
  Object.assign = function(target, varArgs) { // .length of function is 2
    'use strict';
    if (target == null) { // TypeError if undefined or null
      throw new TypeError('Cannot convert undefined or null to object');
    }

    var to = Object(target);

    for (var index = 1; index < arguments.length; index++) {
      var nextSource = arguments[index];

      if (nextSource != null) { // Skip over if undefined or null
        for (var nextKey in nextSource) {
          // Avoid bugs when hasOwnProperty is shadowed
          if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(nextSource, nextKey)) {
            to[nextKey] = nextSource[nextKey];
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return to;
  };
}

const data = [
  [{
    name: "item 3",
    value: 2
  }],
  [{
    name: "item 4",
    value: 4535
  }, {
    name: "item 5",
    value: 897
  }]
];

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {

  const newData = data.map(subArr =>
    subArr.map((currentItem, index) => (Object.assign(currentItem, {
      position: index - (subArr.length - 1) * 0.5
    })))
  );

  console.log(newData);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry I don't use Jquery in the productive code. Would you mind providing a solution for the IE without using Jquery?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.assign()` (https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Object/assign) instead of spread operator:

```
Object.assign({}, currentItem, position)
```

Comment: is it supported by IE 9?

Comment: Nope, you need a polyfil.

Comment: Sorry, didn't catch that you need it in IE9.

Comment: So is there a solution for this?

Comment: section Polyfill: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Polyfill

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correct, you can use Object.defineProperty, looks like it supported in IE [enter link description here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

```
  const data = [
  [{
    name: "item 3",
    value: 2
  }],
  [{
    name: "item 4",
    value: 4535
  }, {
    name: "item 5",
    value: 897
  }]
];

let newData = data.map(arr => {
    let obj = {};
    arr.map((item, index) => {
        Object.defineProperty(obj, 'position', {
            value: index - (arr.length - 1) * 0.5,
            configurable: true
        });
    });
    return obj;
});

console.log(newData);
```