# Spread inside JSON reviver function

Tags: javascript, json

I Would like to be able to spread out the value of an entry inside a `JSON.parse` reviver function while also drop the original key.
Returning a spreaded value doesn't seem to do that trick.

here is an example:

```js
const json = {a: 'foo', b: {c: 1, d: '2'}}
const stringify = JSON.stringify(json)

const parsed = JSON.parse(stringify, function(k, v) {
  if(k === 'b') {
    return {...v}
  } else {
    return v
  }
})

document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = `<pre>${JSON.stringify(parsed, null, 2)}</pre>`;
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

In the above the desired output should be

```json
{
  "a": "foo",
  "c": 1,
  "d": "2"
}
```

Comment: Codesandbox link doesn't seem to show an example. It is preferred if you keep your question contained within Stack Overflow itself, you can do this by creating a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) if you want to create a runnable example of code.

Comment: @NickParsons Yeah my bad. should be fine now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I wouldn't recommend it as it's not very intuitive, you can use `Object.assign(this, v)` to merge with the `this` value in your replacer. This merges object at the `b` property into the object that the `b` property appears in, temporarily giving you:

```js
{a: 'foo', b: {c: 1, d: '2'}, c: 1, d: '2'}
```

and then `b` is removed as we return `undfined` for that path, giving:

```js
{a: 'foo', c: 1, d: '2'}
```

```js
const json = {a: 'foo', b: {c: 1, d: '2'}};
const stringify = JSON.stringify(json)

const parsed = JSON.parse(stringify, function(k, v) {
  if(k === 'b') {
    Object.assign(this, v);
  } else {
    return v;
  }
});

document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = `<pre>${JSON.stringify(parsed, null, 2)}</pre>`;
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON.parse reviver only transform the value that is at key "b" and set it on that key. I would picture it similar to a map.
Your solution should be outside the reviver function. Here is a sample of how your code could look like:

```js
let { b, ...parsed } = JSON.parse(stringify);
if (b) {
  parsed = { ...parsed, ...b };
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I get it but this is very simplified example. in realty the object is complex and nested so working outside the reviver will require some work.

Answer (score 0):

@Geo Mircean answer is correct, but your comment add new information to the question.

If you have a complex structure, I don't think there is an easier option. The first one that comes to mind is to iterate the object and see if you need to spread each field. The logic to tell if you need to spread is up to you, but it will be something like:

```js
let parsed = {...jsonObject};
for(let key in jsonObject)
{
  if (typeof jsonObject[key] === 'object') // if you want to spread
  {
    delete parsed[key]; // delete the actual key
    Object.assign(parsed, jsonObject[key]); // add fields to object
  }
}
```

Notice that the `parsed` variable will have our result. At first it get the whole object, then we iterate over the result, delete the field and spread the field value itself.

The `Object.assign` came from [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51477212/2084091) and does not work in IE9 (but I personally don't care about that).